# How to run a bash with shortcut on awesome WM

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, shortcut, awesome-wm

I'm new in Awesome WM and try to add a custom shortcut to run a bash file but it does not work.

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Control", "Shift" }, function () awful.util.spawn(./layout-ir.sh) end),
```

I add this behind of "Standard Program".

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I assume that you are using awesome 3.4.something since you tagged this as [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu). Then: You don't specify key for your shortcut, only modifiers. And lastly: you should use full path for command you want to run and put it in double quotations.

See example for binding Shift-e to run script from user home folder:

```
awful.key({ modkey,   "Shift" }, "e", function () awful.util.spawn("sh /home/USERNAME/myscript.sh") end),
```

Comment: Thanks, yes i use awesome 3.4.13 and ubuntu 12.10. Unfortunately it - just like another answer - does not work > awful.key({ modkey, "Control" }, "o", function () awful.util.spawn("sh /home/hertkof/layout-ir.sh") end),

Comment: try without the `sh` preceeding `/home/hertkof...`. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide full path to `awful.util.spawn`, say `awful.util.spawn("~/.bin/layout-ir.sh")`.

Another mistake is you need to provide the key as second parameter for `awful.key`. So if you want to bind `Win+Control+Shift+k` as your shortcut, you need the following line:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Control", "Shift" }, "k", function () awful.util.spawn("~/.bin/layout-ir.sh") end),
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

awful.util.spawn_with_shell("./layout-ir.sh")